# Существуют ли слова "рисован", "рисованы"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Не могу найти в современных словарях слово "рисован", например, в таком предложении "Узор на стекле рисован морозом".

А есть ли вообще такое слово? Употреблеятся ли оно без приставки?

Находил лишь одну [ссылку](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD), но как-то не очень уж убедительно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существует.

[Орфографический словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

**рисованный**; *кр. ф.* **-ан, -ана**

[Толковый словарь Ушакова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1010394)

**РИСО́ВАННЫЙ**, рисованная, рисованное; **рисован, рисована, рисовано**. прич. страд. прош. вр. от *рисовать*. *Портрет пастелью, рисованный известным художником.*

[Большая биографическая энциклопедия](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD&stype=0)

> Александр  — монах Соловецкого монастыря; по словам тамошнего
>   ризничего, гравировал большой вид монастыря, помеченный, впрочем,
>   именем гравера Ал. Афанасьева (в 1850 году). **Этот вид рисован с
>   натуры** монахом Александром Заливским; по всей вероятности, ризничий
>   перемешал этого рисовальщика, монаха Александра, с гравером
>   Александром Афанасьевым, который гравировал эту доску в Москве (как и
>   значится на ней) и монахом не был.

[Александр Трубицин (из сб. "Музыка моей души")](https://books.google.ru/books?id=WHT3CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&lpg=PT38&dq=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D1%8F%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8E:%20%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E,%20%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB&source=bl&ots=S6lLMzWa3_&sig=ACfU3U30kdO1HcC1kCAUKeJ5lSxyKyLfrA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNmLnd3_jfAhXRhqYKHcLpAm4Q6AEwCHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%20%D1%8F%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%8E%3A%20%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E%2C%20%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB&f=false)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]